# User registration creates unique URL

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My query is based around this previously asked question,
[How to create a specific URL for a user during registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310744/how-to-create-a-specific-url-for-a-user-during-registration)

This is the process I am after:

- User registers to create a page and unique page url
- Page gets created along with the unique ‘domain.co.uk/unique-page-url’ where the user can see (and later edit) their page
- Potentially password protected with an extra passcode requested during registration so only they can see it

Although I have read the question above and found many tutorials to automate sub-domain creation (which isn’t really what I am after) I am still a little confused as to how this can be achieved.

I have an idea on what the registration form needs to include and how to rewrite URL's however it’s how the ‘unique-page-url’ is actually created and applied that I am confused with. I hope this makes sense as I know what I want to achieve, I am just not 100% sure on how to word my question that makes it different from the previously asked question. Perhaps if someone could helpfully explain the URL creation process to me and how it is handled, that is all I need.

Regards,
AbsoDesigner

Comment: You are not as specific as you should be. You can always create a new directory in your htdocs directory and copy a default index.html into that directory. This index.html could then be modified by some php script. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I would say you want to pass the unique ID as a URL parameter and then use .htaccess to write the ID after the /. Lots of tuts for that kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user choose the url and check for uniqueness at the registration process or let the database generate an unique id per auto increment.

To find the specific user you have to parse the url. A quick example:

```
<?php

$permalink = current( explode( "/", trim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/" ) ) );

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE permalink = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, $permalink) . "'";
```

If you are using Apache as http server you need to create a .htaccess file in your project directory to redirect all not existing files to your index.php:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```